# Suppress output of file creation in git from commit

Tags: git, bash

When I create a bare repo and push to it , my console gets clogged ...

[image]
Is there a way to suppress all this output of "created" files.

It is correct but I just don't want the output.

```
resetBareServer(){
    ssh $server1 -t  "cd ~; rm -rf ~/root.git; mkdir root.git; cd root.git; git init --bare;"
    ( cd ~/root; push server1; )
}
```

Thanks.

Note the commit is causing all the output.

Comment: There is no `git commit` command in your script. There is a mystery `push` command which is *not* `git push`. We can *guess* that `push` is an alias or shell function you wrote that runs `git commit`, but here you are hiding critical information from us, then asking that we help you with an issue that you are obscuring.

Answer (score 0):

--quiet?

`git clone --quiet`

works with init too, apparently.

Comment: the commit is causing all the output however.

Comment: commit also has --quiet option..... plus, would you consider redirecting output? ```git init blah blah > /dev/null``` ... or even ```&> /dev/null```. That should skip ***all*** output.

Answer (score 0):

what does `push` do?

from `man git commit`

```
   -q, --quiet
       Suppress commit summary message.
```

Comment: the commit is causing all the output however. – zen just now   edit